how to terminate java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Maximizer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int n = input.nextInt();
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int value = input.nextInt();
        max = (value > max) ? value : max;
        }
    System.out.println("The largest number was " + max + ".");
    }
}


Hi, i want to run this code with Linux Terminal through entering java Maximizer and then entering a list. After that, i press the 'ENTER' button but it wont run, but keep allowing me to enter more inputs. How can I terminate this through Terminal. Thanks

What is your issue? It won't run, or it won't stop? You can terminate a running program by pressing Ctrl-C. As you've written it, it will prompt for as many numbers as the first number you entered. Did you enter a very high number for the first number?

Another alternative is an end-of-file indication: by default ^D on Linux, ^Z on Windows.

For us to be able to answer your question, please be very precise: Which numbers did you enter, if any? What behaviour had you expected? When had you expected it not to accept any more input?

Also excuse me for asking, Did you write this code yourself? Do you understand how it is supposed to work? Just so we know whether this is an implicit part of your question.

(Not what you meant, but a simple and brutal way to terminate the program is to type something that is not a number. This will cause an exception from input.nextInt(), which in turn will make the program crash.)

Try entering 1 2. After that your program will print a message and stop. Next time try 2 1 0 and see what happens. Try 0. Try -1. Finally try 1.5.

you forgot to call input.close() after exiting your loop

input is wrapping System.in. You should not close it. The rule is, always close everything that you open, but you did not open System.in, so don't close it.

Also, if it was wrapping, say, a stream from a file, instead of stdin, then you should close it in a finally block or by using try-with-resources, not just close it after the loop in code that might not be reached (if an exception occurred).

Thanks for wanting to contribute. In addition to what @DavidConrad says calling input.close() after the loop will not help at all.

I'm not sure what is the right answer and what is wrong, but for me, after i put input.close() it worked perfectly. That's why I checked the green tick. But of course thanks for all the answers and comments! Is helpful to think more about it

@happyday I am first of all glad that you got your problem solved. I remain skeptical as to whether the input.close()did that or something unrelated that you likely are not aware of.You may experiment with taking it out again (commenting it out using //) and back in and verify whether it really makes the difference that you thought.
